# How to use setOnAction event on javafx

Tags: javafx, eventhandler

I would like to validate if a textfield is empty or not using javafx.

I am confused of event handlers. I want to confirm : 
- whether there are many ways to use setOnAction :

```
submit.setOnAction((new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { 
     public void handle(MouseEvent event) { 
        System.out.println("Hello World"); 
     } 
    }));
```

or

```
submit.setOnAction(e -> handle(e));
```

what is the difference between these two choices?

- whether the second choice can not use the ActionEvent
  submit.setOnAction(e -> handle());
  but then what is the purpose of defining e?

I would like to validate textfields in my application.

```
public class AppGUI extends Application{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch();
}


public void start(Stage topView)
{
    createUI(topView);
}

private void createUI(Stage topView)
{
    TextField name = TextField();
    Button submit = new Button("Submit");
    submit.setOnAction(e -> validate());
}
private boolean validate()
{
   // if textfield is empty, return false. else, return true. 
}
```

I am lost here. Is it okay if the e in setOnAction is not used in validate? How do I pass the value of textfield to validate()? is making the textfields private variables the only way? (because I have so many text fields I wonder if its a good option). 
in createUI method, how do i say if validate() returns false, show error message and if true, do something else? 
Thank you and sorry for bothering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what is the difference between these two choices?

In second option [lambdas](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html) are used (appeared since Java 8)

> but then what is the purpose of defining e?

For a button your method have a signature like this `setOnAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler)` You should see [EventHandler tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javafx/javafx_event_handling) and an [ActionEvent javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/ActionEvent.html). For instance, from e you can get the object on which the Event initially occurred this way `e.getSource()`

It is ok if you don't use e in validate.

To pass the value of textfield your method should have signature like this

```
boolean validate(String text);
```

Code example:

```
private void createUI(Stage topView){
  TextField name = TextField();
  Button submit = new Button("Submit");

  submit.setOnAction(e -> {
      boolean validated = validate(name.getText());
      if(validated) System.out.println("validated"); 
  });
}

private boolean validate(String text){
  return text != null && !text.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: How do i proceed checking the value returned by validate and do something else ?

Comment: I recommend pointing to the doc for `EventHandler`, not `ActionEvent`, since this contains the interface structure relevant in this case.